# backtick character to create a string template in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, templates

I am trying to format string with dynamically result set. m using backtick(template) operator but it's working only with one lever. as we have complex nested data structure it's difficult to format nested level string with template.

Actual Return:

```
"formattedSting": "format1 ${a}, ${b}, ${c}"
```

Expected output:

```
"formattedSting": "format1 av1, bv1, cv1"
```

Any idea how to solve this issue without eval or simple replace method.

```js
// mockSteps - coming from static ts file and m not able to replace quot(") with backtick(`)
mockSteps = {
 'steps': [{
  'id': 1,
  'format': "format1 ${a}, ${b}, ${c}"
 },{
  'id': 2,
  'format': "format2 ${a}, ${c}"
 },{
  'id': 3,
  'format': "format3 ${b}, ${a}"
 }]
};
 
list = [
  {a:'av1',b:'bv1',c:'cv1'},  
  {a:'av2',b:'bv2',c:'cv2'}
];

resultList = [];
list.forEach((lst) => {
   const {a, b, c } = lst;
   const formatObj = mockSteps['steps'][0].format;
   result = {
    keyword : '...',
    // formattedSting : eval('`' + formatObj + '`'),
        formattedSting : `${formatObj}`
   };
   resultList.push(result);
});

console.log(resultList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add backticks to the object inside your array inside your object.

```
mockSteps = {
    'steps': [{
        'id': 1,
        'format': `format1 ${a}, ${b}, ${c}`
    },{
        'id': 2,
        'format': `format2 ${a}, ${c}`
    },{
        'id': 3,
        'format': `format3 ${b}, ${a}`
    }]
};
```

Comment: If i do that i got js error variable a, b, c not defined.
m running this in angularjs ERROR in src/core/abc.ts(10,21): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'a'.

Comment: Backticks aren't valid JSON, so you'd still have to wrap them into `"` if they come from a JSON file that gets parsed.

Comment: @Shilly I didn't read that light grey comment ahah, thought it was a generated object he created himself.

Comment: you mean need to change my step obj like this? 
  'format': " '`' format1 ${a}, ${b}, ${c} '`' "

Comment: No well, as @Shilly pointed out I didn't get that its coming from a static json, other than some replace functions, regex or similar in that case, as it is static, I can't think on another third option on how you can achieve what you need.

Comment: Yes true it's coming from static ts file. mockSteps object is in that file. for simplification i just copy/past in sample.

Answer (score 0):

`new Function()` could be used, but that's basically the same as `eval()`.

Personally I use `string.replace()` for these cases.

If you don't want to `.replace()` or `Function()`, I'd opt to actually change the format into something easier to parse.

```js
const mockSteps = {
  "steps": [
    { "id": 1, "format": [ "a", "b", "c" ] },
    { "id": 2, "format": [ "a", "c" ] },
    { "id": 3, "format": [ "b", "a" ] }
  ]
};

const data = [
  {a:'av1',b:'bv1',c:'cv1'},  
  {a:'av2',b:'bv2',c:'cv2'}
];

const resultList = mockSteps.steps.reduce(( collection, item ) => {
  data.forEach( data => collection.push({
    keyword: '...',
    formattedString: `format${ item.id } ${ item.format.map( ref => data[ ref ]).join( ', ' ) }`
  }));
  return collection;
}, [] );

console.log(resultList);
```

Comment: We can't change format bcoz it's just business rule defined as format. m just try to write nice and clean logic with new template format. i can leave with replace option as of now.! Thanks.!

Answer (score 0):

```js
mockSteps = {
 'steps': [{
  'id': 1,
  'format': "format1 ${a}, ${b}, ${c}"
 },{
  'id': 2,
  'format': "format2 ${a}, ${c}"
 },{
  'id': 3,
  'format': "format3 ${b}, ${a}"
 }]
};
 
list = [
  {'${a}':'av1', '${b}':'bv1', '${c}':'cv1'},  
  {'${a}':'av2', '${b}':'bv2', '${c}':'cv2'}
];

resultList = [];
list.forEach((lst) => {
      let formatObj = mockSteps.steps[0].format;
      for(let key of Object.keys(lst)) {
       formatObj = formatObj.replace(key, lst[key]);
      }

      result = {
 keyword : '...',
 formattedSting : `${formatObj}`
      };
     resultList.push(result);
});

console.log(resultList);
```

this is one of ways that you can do, here I just changed your `list` object keys names to that what we need to replace, then added `list` object keys in loop and replaced matched results with values